# Nullable foreign keys - good or bad practice?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Let's assume I have 2 tables: **foo** and **bar**.

In third table I want to store different kind of data, however every row will have a reference to either **foo** OR **bar**.

Is it correct if I create 2 `NULL`able foreign keys - **foo_id** and **bar_id** - in the third table, or is it againts database design principles?

Basically, I thought all the time that foreign keys need to ALWAYS have a "parent", so if I try to e.g. `INSERT` a row with no primary key matched (or, in this case, with a foreign key set to `NULL`), I will get an error. Nullable FK-s are new to me, and they feel a bit off.

Also, what are the alternatives? Is it better to create separate tables storing single reference? Isn't this creating redundancy?

Linking tables?

Help.

Comment: I get what you are asking for, but for the future UML diagram says more than 1000 words.

Comment: I try to *avoid* nullable FK's - as much as practical. A good database engine (take your pick on if MySQL fits in this category) has no problem with "extra" join tables to represent this multiplicity rule. Using another table definitely does *not* implicitly break normalization or "database rules" but it does require a different approach to queries and structure - albeit one that I recommend pursuing. (As far as redundancy: there has to be redundant data and/or functional dependencies for this to exist; adding a "linking table" does not imply either.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nullable FK is "okay". You will still get an error when you try to insert a non-existing parent key (it is just `NULL` that is allowed now).

The alternative is two link tables, one for `foo` and one for `bar`.

Things to consider:

- Link tables allow for 1:N. If you don't want that, you can enforce it by primary key on the link table. That is not necessary for the id column solution (they are always 1:N).
- You can avoid columns with mostly `NULL` values using link tables. In your case, though, it seems that you have NULL for exactly half the values. Probably does not qualify as "mostly". This becomes more interesting with more than two parent tables.
- You may want to enforce the constraint that exactly one of your two columns is `NULL`. This can be done with the id column version using a check constraint. It cannot be done with link tables (unless you use triggers maybe).

Comment: Thanks. Currently I'm using two link tables for that purpose, however it requires more complex quering approach etc. I didn't fully get the third item on your list. Do you mean setting a composite index on the two foreign keys in order to make sure at least one is always `NULL`?

Comment: Not an index, just a `CHECK` constraint. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

Comment: I see, neat. Does breaking the `CHECK` throw an error or fail silently, while e.g. `INSERT`ing?

Comment: It would fail in the same way as violating other constraints (such as NOT NULL).

Comment: @lesssugar Having two FKs, of which one must be not-null is an "exclusive arc" - I on rare occasion find such warranted, but it can also be indicative of a design issue. SQL simply has no DRI support for distributed FKs, as much would be handy in a more general sense. I recommend using VIEWS to simplify queries - make the database work for you, not the other way around.

Answer (score -1):

it is depend on the business logic of the program. if the foreign key field must has a value , it is bad to set it null-able .

for example . 
a book table has `category_id` field which the value is reference from `bookCategory` table.

each record in book table must has category . if for some reason you set it as nullable . this will cause some record in book table with `category_id` is null.

the problem will show up in report. the following 2 query will return different `total_book`

```
select count(*) as total_book from book;
```

---

```
select 
   count(*) as total_book 
from 
   book 
   inner join bookCategory 
      on book.category_id = category.id
```

---

my advice is don't use null-able  unless you expect value and no-value . alot of complex system that sometime have value different from one report and another , usually is cause by this.